# Editing Fortran90 in a fixed format mode

Tags: formatting

I am currently writing a user-script for a simulation software, and the program requires the use of Fortran90 syntax in 132-columns fixed format.

Emacs has two Fortran modes that I know of, `fortran-mode` and `f90-mode`. Fixed formmat is not supported in `f90-mode` so I am stuck using `fortran-mode`. The number of columns can be fixed, but the syntax highlighting is not correct.

- Keywords such as `use`, `contains`, `intent`, `dimension`, `end subroutine <name>` are not recognized.
- Variables aren't being highlighted after the `::` operator.

While these are simple inconveniences and they do not affect the programming experience much, Emacs is all about convenience. So my question is:

Is there a simple way to achieve the `f90-mode`syntax highlighting in `fortran-mode`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is nothing to stop you from using F90 highlighting in `fortran-mode`.  Just put something like this in your config:

```
(require 'f90)
(add-hook 'fortran-mode-hook 'f90-font-lock-2)
```

where the number at the end (1 to 4) controls the degree of gaudiness. Here is an example with the default color scheme and `f90-font-lock-4` (maximum gaudiness).

[image]

Comment: All those cases are colored for me at levels 3 and above.  You can see `only` in the screenshot above (at level 4).  Is this not the case for you?